# Need Advice for the purposes of learning

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I would really like to make a multiplayer mod for Fallout 4, I know how to program and i have a basic understanding of how to get opcodes and read/write to those. Now what i don't understand is how to find specific functions such as some sort of spawning function so i can spawn an npc to act as another player.

I guess what i need is specific books or tutorials that will help with reversing functions or looking for specific functions to call. Any help would be greatly appreatiated.

Comment: This is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from official Bethesda website Community for mods developers:

https://bethesda.net/community/category/134/mod-relz-and-wips

And if there is no proper information there - grab some mod that implement features/functions you looking for from mods directory: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4 and RE it.

Here you will find all sorts of manuals on how to begin RE, tools and techniques.

Good luck )

D.L.

Comment: Thanks for the info but in order to make a multiplayer mod i have to make a client that hooks into the game and i can't use the actual modding system itself to do so. I need to actually reverse the game itself to do the things i'm looking to do.

Comment: So load it in IDA and go ahead :)